# Using document.getElementById not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have 2 html files and an external js file. The first html file prints out images and their names. The images are clickable and their names are stored in 2 arrays in the external js file. When the image is clicked, I want to get the name of the clicked image in the external js file and print that image in the second html file.

1st html file

```
<body>
   <p>
   <script type = "text/javascript">
      for (var i = 0; i < pic.length; i++) {
          document.write("<a href=\"specify.html\"><img id=\"image\" src = \" " + pics[i] + "\"></a>" + "<br>");
          document.write(name[i] + "<br>");
      }
  </script>
  <p>
</body>
```

External js file, assume that the arrays are not empty.

```
var pic = new Array();
var name = new Array();
var image = document.getElementById("image").src;
```

2nd html, specify.html

```
document.write("<img src = \" " + image + "\">" + "<br>");
```

The value of the image variable is undefined. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help.

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple id of the same values. If pic.length > 1, what image do you want to get the src value of?

Comment: Did you get document.write from w3schools? You should avoid using it. Instead create elements with document.createElement and then place them on the page with element.appendChild. Part of the reason your external script cannot find any elements (aside from the unique id point from Aziz) is that the page is not loaded yet and those elements are not on the DOM when the script executes. You should read up on the window.load event. When you search for javascript related keywords, try adding in "MDN" (Mozilla Developers Network), it is a more technically accurate site.

Comment: @AzizSaleh, I want to get the src of any clicked image.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as pointed out by @Aziz-Saleh, you shouldn't repeat ids in your page. Try adding a number to the id.

Secondly, I'm not sure if I get what you're trying to do, but it seems you want to *set a variable in one page, and print that variable in another page without storing it elsewhere.*

If I'm correct, you can do it the way you're doing. It seems you don't understand how HTML pages, or HTTP, works.

Each HTML page is like a differente application. Each time your page loads, the external js file is parsed and executed. It doesn't matter how many times before you had loaded it, or what modificiatons you had made to the variables. When a new page loads, e everything gets it's default value. So, even if you set the image file in the first page, it is undefined in the second, until you assign a value to it.

Try this:

```
<body>
   <p>
   <script type = "text/javascript">
      for (var i = 0; i < pic.length; i++) {
          document.write('<a class="images" href="specify.html"><img src="' + pics[i] + '\" data-index="' + i + '"></a><br>' + name[i] + '<br>');
      }

      document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          var index = this.getAttribute('data-index');
          if (index !== undefined) {
               document.location = 'specify.html#' + index;
               e.preventDefault();
          }
      }, false);
  </script>
  <p>
</body>
```

In `specify.html` ...

```
var index = document.location.hash.substr(1);
document.write("<img src = \" " + pics[index] + "\">" + "<br>");
```

What I'm doing, basically, is get the index of the image clicked and request the second page passing this index as part of the URL. In the second page, I get that index back fromt the hash part (the part in a url that it's placed after an `#`) and then write the image that corresponds to the index.

As othe people has pointed, document.write() is very old. I suggest you to read about the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference) and the [page lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981239/html-page-life-cycle)

Comment: I tried this, but I still get undefined which is the same as before. Also, should I change the name of the variable index in specify.html or is it the same as the one in the 1st html file?